# Continue loop on array after it's over

Tags: javascript

I have an array with length of 26, each element a letter of the alphabet. I also have an N which can be from -10 to 10. 
The N takes the letter and changes it this way.
if my letter is 'a' and N = 2 my 'a' will become 'c', if my letter is 'c' and N = -1 my 'c' will become 'b'.

When i have a letter like 'z' which is the last element of the array and i give N a value it returns undefined.

How can I make it continue to loop on the array. For example if my letter is 'y' and N = 5 then it will give me a 'd'. Hope you understood me xD.

Comment: Can you post your javascript code? I think you're almost there! I think you could add a check on your letter + N and loop back to beginning if needed. But I can't be sure without seeing where you are in your code.

Comment: Without your code it is not clear what you are asking, but you could use a modulus to get the position of your new letter: 'p = (i+N) % 26;' Then p is your new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `Caesar shift` problem where we shift the alphabets based on a given shift count(N).

We have to make use of `str.charCodeAt` and `String.fromCharCode` method to solve this.

```
function caesarShift(str, amount) {

    // Wrap the amount
    if (amount < 0)
        return caesarShift(str, amount + 26);

    // Make an output variable
    var output = '';

    // Go through each character
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        // Get the character we'll be appending
        var c = str[i];

        // If it's a letter...
        if (c.match(/[a-z]/i)) {

            // Get its code
            var code = str.charCodeAt(i);

            // Uppercase letters
            if ((code >= 65) && (code <= 90))
                c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 65 + amount) % 26) + 65);

            // Lowercase letters
            else if ((code >= 97) && (code <= 122))
                c = String.fromCharCode(((code - 97 + amount) % 26) + 97);

        }

        // Append
        output += c;

    }

    // All done!
    return output;

};
```

Try working solution on link - https://jsitor.com/5GG7XuWUk

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement in your loop.

```
if (i + N > alphabet.Length) alphabet[i] = alphabet[N+i - alphabet.Length]
```